# Why for the transient state k of a Markov chain is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=k)=0$ true?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

$(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}}$ is a discrete Markov Chain with transitive states $k\in\mathbb{N}$. I have to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=k)=0$. I have an idea that we can rewrite
\begin{align*}
\{X_{n}=k\}=\{X_{1}=X_{n}=k\}\bigcup \{X_{1}\neq k,X_{2}=X_{n}=k\}\bigcup...\bigcup\{X_{1}\neq...\neq X_{n-1}\neq k, X_{n}=k\}
\end{align*}

And then somehow use the fact that $p_{kk}(j)=\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=k|X_{0}=k)<1$ because of transitivity, and maybe because of homogeneity getting something like $(p_{kk}(j))^{n}$ for $n\to \infty$. Would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When $k$ is transient, the probability $p:=\mathbb P_k(\forall n\ge1:X_n\neq k)$ to completely escape from $k$ (i.e., of never returning to $k$)
is positive, and the number
$$N(k):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf1_{\{X_n=k\}}$$ of visits in $k$ (or the number of “attempts” so as to completely escape from $k$) has the geometric distribution with success parameter $p$ (this is justified by the Markov property). In particular $\mathbb E_k[N(k)]=\frac1p<\infty$ (because $p>0$). But then (by Fubini-Tonelli's theorem)
$$\mathbb E_k[N(k)]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P_k(X_n=k)<\infty,$$
which implies that $\mathbb P_k(X_n=k)\longrightarrow0$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

**Addendum.** Let now $\ell\neq k$ be another state. Let $T:=\inf\,\{n\ge1:X_n=k\}$. Under $\mathbb P_\ell$, we have $X_n\neq k$ for all $n<T$. Thus, by the strong Markov property at $T$,
$$\mathbb E_\ell[N(k)]=\mathbb E_\ell\!\left[\mathbf1_{\{T<\infty\}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{\{X_{n+T}=k\}}\right]=\mathbb E_\ell\!\left[\mathbf 1_{\{T<\infty\}}\,\mathbb E_{X_T}[N(k)]\right]=\mathbb P_\ell(T<\infty)\,\mathbb E_k[N(k)],$$
and in particular $\mathbb E_\ell[N(k)]\le\mathbb E_k[N(k)]$.
Hence if $\mathbb E_k[N(k)]<\infty$, then for any starting distribution $\mu$, $$\mathbb E_\mu[N(k)]:=\int\mu(\mathrm d\ell)\,\mathbb E_\ell[N(k)]\le\left(\int\mu(\mathrm d\ell)\right)\mathbb E_k[N(k)]=\mathbb E_k[N(k)]<\infty.$$
Since (again, by Fubini-Tonelli's theorem) $$\mathbb E_\mu[N(k)]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P_\mu(X_n=k),$$
we have $\mathbb P_\mu(X_n=k)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$.

Comment: sorry, I don't really get, how $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=k)<\infty$ implies $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=k)\to 0$

Comment: @AnnaShevchenko A necessary condition for the series $\sum_{n\ge0}x_n$ to converge is $x_n\longrightarrow0$.

Comment: (Let $S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^nx_k$ be the partial sum. If the series converges (say to $\ell$), then $x_n=S_n-S_{n-1}\longrightarrow\ell-\ell=0$.)

Comment: ,sorry for asking one more time, but should not the expected value be conditional?

Comment: It does not matter. You can multiply out by $\mathbb P(X_0=k)$.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: I am sorry for reasking you again, however I have started to writing it down and I have noticed that it is not true in general, that we can multiply it out. So why can we do this in this case? I though more about $P(X_{n}=k)=P(X_{n}=k|X_{0}=k)P(X_{0}=k)$, kind of a formula of total probabilities, where we know that $X_{0}=k$.

Comment: @AnnaShevchenko no worries. By definition, a Markov chain has a starting distribution. I assumed it was $\delta_k$ (i.e., the chain starts at state $k$). If that's not the case, you can anyway show by the Markov property that, for every state $\ell\neq k$, $$\mathbb  E[N(k)\mid X_0=\ell]=\mathbb P(\exists n\ge 1:X_n=k\mid X_0=\ell)\,\mathbb E[N(k)\mid X_0=k]$$
(read “the mean number of visits at $k$ starting from $\ell$, equals the mean number of visits at $k$ starting from $k$, provided that we can reach $k$ first”). You then obtain $\mathbb E_\mu[N(k)]<\infty$ for any starting distribution.

Comment: Okay, I do understand the case with $\mathcal{l}\neq k$. I have already written down $\mathbb{E}[N(K)|X_{0}=k]=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}P(X_{n}=k|X_{0}=k)<\infty$, so because of the geometric distribution and theorem of Fubini we get that it is finite, so that the state k would be visited only finitely many times. And after I want to go to $\mathbb{E}[N(k)]=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}$, and exactly here I am struggling to find an argumentation why we can follow this from the previous result.

Comment: @AnnaShevchenko I edited my answer, providing more details. Intuitively, it should be clear that the mean number of visits at $k$ is finite whatever the starting state is (otherwise, the state would not be transient). I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!